# Load a second kernel at boot

Tags: kernel, boot, kexec

At boot, the bootloader loads a kernel, let's say vmlinuz1. Is there a way to pass some kind of parameters to it in order to chainload another kernel (let's say vmlinuz2)? I know `kexec` can load another kernel but I don't know if it can run automatically at boot.

Comment: AFAIK there's no such parameter in the Linux kernel but you can always patch it to have this feature.

Comment: Any program can be launched automatically at boot.

Comment: I meant even before starting any service

Comment: Assuming you're using grub2, try Google for "grub2 chainloading".